# erl_interface linker error

Tags: c, gcc, erlang, erl-interface

I need to use **erl_interface** in my C-program. There is Erlang R15B01 on Debian Wheezy.

I just do the following (for example).

```
// main.c
#include <ei.h>
#include <erl_interface.h>

int main() {
    erl_init(NULL,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Then i say:

```
cc -I/usr/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.7/include -L/usr/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.7/ -lei -lerl_interface -o prog main.c
```

Directory specified as -L contains `libei.a` and `liberl_interface.a` but linker abusing that reference to erl_init is undefined: `undefined reference to erl_init`

What may be wrong? Sorry for really stupid question.

Comment: I suspect your -L path is wrong. check exactly where those libraries resides. it should have been "-L/usr/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.7/lib"

Comment: Yes, of course, I try to build this specifying "-L/usr/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.7/lib". I've just misspelled, when writing my question. libei.a and liberl_interface.a realy resides here. And more - linker see this files but can not find function definitions.

Comment: try switching the order of libraries. i.e. -lerl_interface -lei

Comment: Thanks! This not takes any effect. But I found that is not erl_interface trouble. Seems it trouble with my `ld` - it can't link no one other static library, abusing `undefined reference`.

Comment: only thing remains is platform compatibility. I am hoping that your static libraries are compiled for your platform. Otherwise linker would not bother to link.

Comment: @ViacheslavKovalev What if you add `-lei -lerl_interface` to the **very end of the command line?** Like `gcc -o prog -I<include dir> -L<lib dir> main.c -lei -lerl_interface`...

Comment: Yeah!!! Thanks a lot! `cc -o prog -I<include> -L<lib> main.c -lei -lerl_interface` spit out abouth hundreed `undefined references`, but when I swap -lei and -lerl_interface to `cc -o prog -I<include> -L<lib> main.c -lerl_interface -lei`, it was successfully linked. Well, think I need to read mans about gcc more attentively.

Comment: How can I close this question? (I am newbie here)

Comment: @ViacheslavKovalev I'm adding an answer, and you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newest versions of the GNU toolchain require that the object files and libraries be specified in the same order their symbols depend on each other. So you should generally **put the library flags to the end of the invocation,** like this:

```
gcc -o prog main.c -L<libdir> -I<includedir> -lerl_interface -lei
```